# How to split string based on column length and insert into table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a string that I need to split and create table from it.

```
00001                 00000009716496000000000331001700000115200000000000
```

I know the exact length of each column:

```
Col1  = 5 
Col2 = 7
Col3 = 23
etc...
```

I need something like this (Empty values are `NULL`'s)

[image]

Can you direct me to the right way of doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `substring()`:

```
select substring(col, 1, 5) as col1,
       substring(col, 6, 2) as col2,
       . . .
```

Comment: [`NullIf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) can be used to convert "empty" columns into `NULL` values. Converting the values to appropriate data types should also be done where applicable.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use computed column to improve your performance(visit https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-computed-columns/)
2. use below function to fill your column

   ```
   SUBSTRING(string, start, length)
   ```